# OpenGL glDrawBuffer and glBindTexture

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, opengl-3, multipass

I'm still new on opengl3 and I'm trying to create a multipass rendering.
In order to do that, I created FBO, generated several textures and attached them to it with

```
    unsigned index_col = 0;
    for (index_col = 0; index_col < nbr_textures;  ++index_col) 
            glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + index_col, texture_colors[index_col], 0);
```

It works well (I try to believe that I'm doing good here!).

My comprehension problem occurs after, when I try to render in the first texture offscreen, then in the second texture, then render on the screen.
To render to a particular texture, I'm using :

```
FBO.bind();
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO.getColorTextures(0)); //getColorTextures(0) is texture_colors[0]
```

Then I draw, using my shader, and after I would like to do :

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO.getColorTextures(1));
```

and after all

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
RenderToScreen(); // assuming this function render to screen with a quad
```

My question is : 
What is the difference between `glDrawBuffer` and `glBindTexture`? Is it necessary to call both? Aren't textures attached to buffer?  (I can't test it actually, because I'm trying to make it works...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glBindTexture` is connecting a texture with a texture sampler unit for reading. `glDrawBuffer` selects the destination for drawing writes. If you want to select a texture as rendering target use `glDrawBuffer` on the color attachment the texture is attached to; *and make sure that none of the texture sampler units it is currently bound to is used as a shader input!* The result of creating a feedback loop is undefined.

Comment: So basically, actually, what I'm doing is utterly wrong? I need to remove that `glBindTexture` in order to suceed at my task ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`glDrawBuffer` selects the color buffer (in this case of the framebuffer object) that you will write to:

> When colors are written to the frame buffer, they are written into the color buffers specified by glDrawBuffer

If you wanted to draw to multiple color buffers you would have written

```
GLuint attachments[2] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
glDrawBuffers(2, attachments);
```

while `glBindTexture` binds a texture to a texture unit.

They serve different purposes - remember that OpenGL and its current rendering context behave as a state machine.

Comment: Actually, I want to draw into 1 attachment then into another attachment, not both at same times.
Btw, when I use glDrawBuffers of 2 attachment, what will happen if I switch GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1. which one will correspond to which layer?

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch [Take a look at here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers) for your answer

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look! Thanks for your help! Opengl is not easy-minded when you're not familiar with /: